# factorplot main title overlaps sub titles in seaborn

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, formatting, seaborn

I have produced the below chart. As you can see the main title is overlapping the subtitles of the graphs. I tried different methods but none of them seems to be working. I have also attached my code.

[image]

```
def save_multi_columns_categorical_charts(df, chart, columns, y, hue, title, single_statistic=False,
                                          single_statistic_name=None, kind='point', col='Message Size (Bytes)'):
    filename = chart + ".png"
    print("Creating chart: " + title + ", File name: " + filename)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    all_columns = [col,'Back-end Service Delay (ms)', 'Concurrent Users','Scenario Name']
    all_columns.extend(columns)
    df_results = df[all_columns]

    df_results['new_var'] = df_results[col] + ' - ' + df_results['Scenario Name']


    g = sns.factorplot(x="Concurrent Users", y='Throughput (Requests/sec)',
                       hue='new_var', col='Back-end Service Delay (ms)',
                       data=df_results, kind=kind,
                       size=5, aspect=1, col_wrap=2, legend=False)



    plt.subplots_adjust(top=10, left=0.1)
    g.fig.suptitle(title,y=1.08)  # can also get the figure from plt.gcf()
    plt.legend(loc=2, frameon=True, title="Response Time Summary")

    plt.savefig(filename)
    plt.clf()
    plt.cla()
    plt.close(fig)
```

Comment: If you change `y=1.08` in `g.fig.suptitle` what happens? You might have to adjust the spacing of `top` in `subplots_adjust` too

Answer (score 1):

Try giving the offset of the title from the top of the axes (in points), in order to add some gap between the main title and the underlying graphs as:

> plt.title('Title of the plot', pad=100)

Keep increasing the pad value to adjust the gap as per your need.